# Expresión regular en pythom. Ficheros en url

Tags: python, regex, archivo, url

Necesito una expresión regular en python que busque un fichero en la URL. Estos son algunos ejemplos de URLs donde se podría encontrar el fichero.

```
http://www.domain.com/static/js/este.js
http://www.domain.com/index.php?a=este.js
http://www.domain.com/index.php?a=/este.js
http://www.domain.com/?v=http://domain.com/static/este.js
http://www.domain.com/?v=http://domain.com/static/?v=http://www.domain/src/este.js&var=lol
```

Los ficheros JSON no valdrían:

```
http://www.domain.com/?v=http://domain.com/static/?v=http://www.domain/src/este.jsON.
```

La expresión regular en "pseudocódigo" sería:

- Que comience por "/" o =. Esto no se captura. Entiendo que sería: /\|=\
- Que contenga n caracteres. Sería el nombre. Se captura. Entiendo que sería: *.
- Que contenga ".js". Sería la extensión. Se captura. Entiendo que sería: ".js"
- Que no contenga despues del ".js" un "on". No se capura. Entiendo que ?^"on".

La expresión regular en Python entiendo que sería algo parecido a esto:

```
'/\|=\(.*".js")?^"on"'
```

Pero no consigo que me funcione.

Comment: ¿Es un ejercicio que tengas que resolver con expresiones regulares, o es un problema real? En el segundo caso te recomiendo usar [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html), módulo estándar.

Comment: Hola:
Es un problema real.
Ya he pensado en utilizar urlib.parse, pero lo he descartado.
En muchas ocasiones ocasiones existen URL que llaman a otras, que llaman a otras, que llaman a otras... y tendría que realizar un bucle, extrar cada una de las URLS y buscar dentro el string "xxx.js".
Entiendo que es más óptimo utilizar una expresión regular directamente en un string (que sería la URL compuesta).
Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

La "expresión regular" que has escrito, no es tal, pues:

- No se usan comillas para delimitar texto literal, como has puesto en `".js"` o `"on"`
- El punto es un carácter especial, debe ir escapado (`\.`)
- La disyuntiva (`|`) no debe ir escapada, y se usa para elegir entre dos posibles expresiones regulares. Para escoger entre dos (o más) caracteres es más práctico usar el conjunto delimitado por corchetes, como por ejemplo `[/=]` para representar un caracter a elegir entre la barra `/` o el igual `=`.
- El operador `.*` te va a coger cualquier caracter, incluyendo `/`, por lo que en lugar de capturarte el nombre del fichero `.js`, te capturaría toda la ruta, como por ejemplo: `domain.com/static/este.js`.

Una posible expresión regular para tu problema sería la siguiente:

```
[/=]([^/=]*\.js)(?:$|[^oO])
```

Significa lo siguiente:

- `[/=]` un caracter inicial que puede ser `/` o  `=`, se supone que será el caracter que aparece justo delante del nombre del fichero.
- `(` iniciamos el grupo de captura, que pretendemos que encaje con el nombre del fichero.

  - `[^/=]*` cualquier cadena de caracteres que no contenga `/` ni `=`
  - `\.js` terminada en `.js`
- `)` terminamos el grupo de captura. Lo que va ahora es para eliminar el caso `json`.
- `(?:` iniciamos un nuevo grupo, pero no quiero que sea capturado. Necesito el grupo porque voy a elegir dos posibles expresiones regulares para lo que sigue, separadas por `|`.

  - `$` es la primera alternativa. Representa el final de la cadena
  - `[^oO]` es la segunda alternativa. Representa un carácter cualquiera con tal de que no sea la `o` (minúscula o mayúscula).

Esta expresión regular se lee como: "Una cadena que comienza por / o por =, tiene más letras (que no son ni / ni =) y lleva al final `.js`, y después o bien se termina la cadena, o bien viene otro carácter que no es la `o`"

Si probamos sobre tus ejemplos:

```
casos = """http://www.domain.com/static/js/este.js
http://www.domain.com/index.php?a=este.js
http://www.domain.com/index.php?a=/este.js
http://www.domain.com/?v=http://domain.com/static/este.js
http://www.domain.com/?v=http://domain.com/static/?v=http://www.domain/src/este.js&var=lol
http://www.domain.com/?v=http://domain.com/static/?v=http://www.domain/src/este.json."""

import re

for caso in casos.split("\n"):
  result = re.findall(r'[/=]([^/=]*\.js)(?:$|[^oO])', caso)
  if result:
    print(result)
  else:
    print("---")
```

Sale:

```
['este.js']
['este.js']
['este.js']
['este.js']
['este.js']
---
```

Comment: Si. Me he liado mezclando lenguajes.
Es lo que necesitaba.
Gracias por la explicación.